# JMesa style disappears when is child of <s:form>

Tags: java, jsp, jmesa

I have an extrange case with JMesa..

When I'm doing tests without a form element as parent (to apply filters and pages) JMesa table is rendered.

But when I put the Jmesa element as form's child, the style disappears and is rendered as a basic table without colors or borders ._.

```
<fieldset>
       <s:form action="listUsers">
        <jmesa:tableModel id="test" items="${users}" var="bean">
            <jmesa:htmlTable caption="${pageScope.caption}" width="100%">
                <jmesa:htmlRow>
                        ... Rows ....
                </jmesa:htmlRow>
            </jmesa:htmlTable>
        </jmesa:tableModel>
       </s:form>
        </fieldset>
```

On head tags I have the css refered and jmesa/jquery.jmesa ..

Answer (score 0):

Since the table renders with correct styles when not wrapped in a form tag but renders with no styling when it is inserted into the body of a form tag, my first thought is that there is a style somewhere at the form tag level that is causing the table styles to be lost or overridden.  Another possibility is that if your [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) are configured with very specific parent/child relationships, the introduction of another tag could conceivably prevent styles from being applied.

Without more information as to what styles are present, the best suggestion I can offer is to use a tool that allows you to interactively assess your styles.  Internet Explorer 8 has the [Developer Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Developer_Tools) feature.  Conveniently, you can use a feature to click on an item on your Web page and it will load that element along with its styles.  You can then analyze the styles or dynamically tweak styles to immediately see results.

I'd recommend loading the page that works and screen capturing the styles for the table when it looks good.  Then you can do the same for when the styles are not being applied to the table and compare the two as a starting point to determining what's causing the difference.